# Where and why is std::nullptr_t in the std namespace?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Firstly, `std::nullptr_t` is a core language type, so why is it in the `std` namespace? You don't see `std::char` or `std::int`.

Secondly, where is it in the `std` namespace? When I right click in Visual Studio to see where it is declared, it says "the symbol nullptr_t is not located in any source file." If `std::nullptr_t` is not declared in the `std` namespace, why does code containing `std::nullptr_t` compile?

EDIT:
[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/fundamental-types-cpp?view=msvc-170) link on microsoft's website says nullptr is a built in type, and that built in types are not defined in header files.

Comment: `std::nullptr_t is a core language type` no, it is not

Comment: `where is it in the std namespace?` Defined in header <cstddef> see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t

Comment: `char` and `int` are *keywords*.  They are reserved and aren't scoped to a namespace.

Comment: No, `std::nullptr_t` is not even a pointer type.

Comment: It's a typedef for an unnamed type. That's all. `using nullptr_t = decltype(nullptr);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> std::nullptr_t is a core language type

`std::nullptr_t` is a fundamental type(aka built in type) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74738449/why-is-the-decltypenullptr-an-unnamed-type). It is not even a pointer type though it can be implicitly converted to any pointer type. Moreover, it is defined inside header `cstddef` in namepsace `std` as quoted below.

This can be seen from [lex.nullptr](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/lex.nullptr#1):

> The pointer literal is the keyword `nullptr`. It is a prvalue of type `std​::​nullptr_­t`.
> [ Note: `std​::​nullptr_­t` is a **distinct type that is neither a pointer type nor a pointer-to-member type**; rather, a prvalue of this type is a null pointer constant and can be converted to a null pointer value or null member pointer value.
> See [conv.ptr] and [conv.mem].
> — end note
>  ]

From [cstddef.syn](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/cstddef.syn):

> Header `<cstddef>` synopsis
>
> ```
> namespace std {
>  using nullptr_­t = decltype(nullptr);
>
>  //other things here
> }
> ```

Comment: This link says nullptr_t is a built in type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/fundamental-types-cpp?view=msvc-170. On that same page it says built in types are not defined in header files. Is std::nullptr_t an exception? I can't find where it is defined in cstddef.

Comment: @beangod See my updated answer where I've mentioned where exactly it is defined in namespace `std`. So it answers your edited question.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason in visual studio, the cstddef document in visual studio does not contain that using statement.

Comment: @beangod Strange. You can also contact msvc support and point this out so that they can further clarify this as VS implementors can say for sure what is happening here in their product. You're welcome.

Comment: I have an update! nullptr_t is aliased in stddef.h, not cstddef.h. I guess this is because csteddef used to be called stddef in the C standard library.

Comment: @beangod I see!

Answer (score 3):

In both libstdc++, libc++, and MSVC's STL, `std::nullptr_t` is a typedef for `decltype(nullptr)`.

So yes, the type is a core language type, but it doesn't have a name, and the only way to refer to it (without the header) is with `decltype(nullptr)`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, `std::nullptr_t` is a special **type**. It is to be distinguished from `nullptr` itself - which is a **value**.

There are some use cases for `std::nullptr_t`.

For example function overloads:

```cpp
void foo(int*);
void foo(nullptr_t);

int main() {
    int a = 4;
    int* b = &a;
    foo(b); // will call foo(int*)
    foo(nullptr); // will call foo(nullptr_t)
    b = nullptr;
    foo(b); // will call foo(int*)
}
```