# Why is the decltype(nullptr) an unnamed type?

Tags: c++, nullptr

`std::nullptr_t` is an alias for `decltype(nullptr)`. The actual type of `nullptr` is unnamed. Why is `std::nullptr_t` an alias to an unnamed type instead of just being a built in type like `int` or `char`? That is like having the type `int` be unnamed and `std::int_t` being an alias to to `decltype(1)`.

EDIT: This question is not a duplicate for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74725969/where-and-why-is-stdnullptr-t-in-the-std-namespace), because that question was asking where `std::nullptr_t` was in the `std` namespace, and assumed that `nullptr_t` was a built in type which it is not. This question is simply asking why `std::nullptr_t` is an alias.

Comment: Of some significance - what you mean by `nullptr_t` is actually `std::nullptr_t`.  It is implemented in the standard library.  Your question could be rephrased as _"Why is something that could be implemented in the language (like `int` or `char`) instead implemented in the standard library?"_

Comment: It would be hard to introduce a name that won't collide with some name in those billions of C++ code lines.

Comment: remember that `nullptr` is meant to be type safe.  That means it needs to becomes the type of the pointer it is assigned to.  This allows for compiler errors when doing things like `int foo = nullptr;` unlike `int foo = NULL;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::nullptr_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t) is its own type so that it may be implicitly converted to any pointer and pointer to member type. It cannot be a built-in type like `int` or even `void*` because it is an actual type, so `nullptr` is not a macro (unlike `NULL`) and `int` or `void*` are not implicitly convertible to other pointer types.

It is technically not named (though I'd say `std::nullptr_t` is its name) because it doesn't need to be named, and reserving another keyword like `int` or `char` just for that would potentially break existing code. Introducing new keywords is never easy.

Example:

```
static constexpr void* VOID_NULL = 0;
static constexpr int INT_NULL = 0;

int main() {
    char* char_ptr = VOID_NULL; // invalid conversion
    int* int_ptr = INT_NULL; // invalid conversion
}
```

It was introduced to fix some issues with the `NULL` macro. Mainly for type safety.

One issue with `NULL` is ambiguous calls to overloads:

```
void f(int*) {}
void f(std::nullptr_t) {}
 
int main() {
    f(NULL); // ambiguous call
    f(nullptr); // fine, calls the std::nullptr_t overload
}
```

Another issue is auto type deduction:

```
void f(int*) {}

int main() {
    auto cloned_nullptr = nullptr;
    auto cloned_NULL = NULL;

    f(cloned_nullptr); // fine
    f(cloned_NULL); // invalid conversion
    // cloned_NULL is actually long int or similar, but not a pointer type
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why is std::nullptr_t an alias to an unnamed type **instead of just being a built in type like int or char?**

This is [CWG 2689](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2689.html) and `std::nullptr_t` is considered to be a **fundamental type**(aka built in type), at least that seems to be the intention . This can be seen from [basic.fundamental](https://wg21.link/basic.fundamental) and [cwg 2689](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2689.html):

> **A type denoted by `cv std::nullptr_t` is a distinct type**. A value of type `std::nullptr_t` is a null pointer constant (7.3.12 [conv.ptr]). Such values participate in the pointer and the pointer-to-member conversions (7.3.12 [conv.ptr], 7.3.13 [conv.mem]). sizeof(std::nullptr_t) shall be equal to `sizeof(void*)`.
>
> **The types described in this subclause are called fundamental types.** [Note 11: Even if the implementation defines two or more fundamental types to have the same value representation, they are nevertheless different types. —end note]

---

Additionally, the same can be seen from [type's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type):

> The C++ type system consists of the following types:
>
> - fundamental types
>
>   - the type `void`
>   - **the type `std::nullptr_t`**
>   - ...

(emphasis mine)

As also mentioned on the above quoted clause from cppreference, `std::nullptr_t` is a fundamental type(aka built in type).